# How to refactor inputs that have HTML5 data-* attributes to work in IE9+

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I'm working from some demo code which has various buttons in HTML5 language like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-method="rotate" data-option="-90" type="button" title="Rotate Left">
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-method="rotate" data-option="90" type="button" title="Rotate Right">
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-method="zoom" data-option="-0.1" type="button" title="Zoom Out">
```

There is a Javascript file associated with this which does this:

```
$(document).on("click", "[data-method]", function () {
      var data = $(this).data();

      if (data.method) {
        $image.cropper(data.method, data.option);
      }
    });
```

The data-* attributes don't work in anything less than IE10. What would be a good way to refactor this code so that it could work in the older browsers.

My initial thoughts so far are:

1. Move the data-method and data-option values into id and class attributes respectively. But then I'd need many if/else statements to perform the correct action per button.
2. Have the data-method and data-option stored in a hidden variable somehow. I have no idea how I would link that to which button was pressed.
3. Do something else yet unknown to me... (hence asking for help on here)... but probably involves jQuery to some extent.

Comment: I don't think it's the data attributes but rather the transformation css isn't available in ie9, though I could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

There's no such method with the data attribute like `data.method` is wrong. And you should get data by using `$(this).data('method')` instead of getting whole data like `$(this).data()`

Try to use like this:

```
var data = $(this).data('method');
if (data) {
   //....
}
```

Comment: But this answer is not explaining how to work around using data-* attributes so that the buttons will still work in older browsers that don't support HTML5 input data attributes. Or does it not matter because they're just attributes which jQuery can work with?